# Create React App and React Toolbox Input

Tags: reactjs, react-toolbox

I'm very new to react and started with Create React App. I added React Toolbox to my project. I have ejected and added css modules to my webpack config file. Most of the React Toolbox components appear correctly after making that change, however React Toolbox's Input component does not look correct. It does not appear styled until you focus the element. On focus it does get some styling, the purple animated bar and label. [See Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Q1Cz.jpg).

Comment: Unrelated, but do you know that [you can use React Toolbox without ejecting](https://github.com/react-toolbox/react-toolbox-themr)?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout https://www.npmjs.com/package/custom-react-scripts. This allows you to customize the react-scripts package without ejecting from create-react-app. It's pretty amazing.